# 'Done' UINavigationBarButtonItem on right side cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, navbar, uinavigationitem

I'm using a UIBarButtonItem with this result:

[image]

I'm using this code to add it to the navigation

```
 self.doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissWebViewController:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.doneButton];
```

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try by drag and drop of UIBarButton Item in navigation bar, later set its value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your navigation bar is larger than your screen. Check it out into your Storyboard. Select the navigation bar, you must see a square at the begining and at the end of the element. If not, move it to fit the screen.

As a reference a Navigation bar for an iphone 6 4.7 inch application is 375 Width.

In addition, review if you have set constraints correctly. Review that your navigation bar has "spacing to nearest neighbor" as 0 for top and -16 for left and right.